# Can I have my vaporizer in my carry on?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

I'm curious if vaporizers(e-cigs) are allowed in carry on luggage.

I will soon fly from USA to Beijing.  I know that vaporizers are legal in both countries.  The only airport restriction I can think of is the liquids rule.  But the liquid in my vaporizer doesn't even come close.

I've actually flown twice (domestic) and kept my vaporizer in my carry on.  But maybe they just didn't notice it when I went through security.

I can't think of any specific reasons why these wouldn't be allowed, but I can't imagine that they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four relevant organizations here.

1. The TSA [permits vaporizers in carry-on luggage, and forbids them in checked baggage](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/electronic-cigarettes-and-vaping-devices).  Liquids are also permitted, [as long as the volume is less than 100 ml](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/e-liquids).
2. The FAA [provides a few additional restrictions](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/more_info/?hazmat=61): they must not be used or charged in flight, and homemade battery packs are forbidden.
3. Chinese safety regulations may also restrict things.
4. Your airline may have restrictions more strict than any of the above, though it's unlikely.

Answer (score -4):

YES.  E-cigarettes and vapor pens are permittee in carry-on bags.

In fact, many airlines and regulatory authorities *require* e-cigarettes to be carried on being prohibited in checked baggage.

The liquid volume must be compliant and, of course, *you many not use the device at any time on board*.

Many, many sources: [https://www.bing.com/search?q=e+cigarettes+carry+on&FORM=AWRE](https://www.bing.com/search?q=e%20cigarettes%20carry%20on&FORM=AWRE)

Comment: Add references please.

Comment: Might I suggest you view the upvoted answer and you might observe why your answer is so pathetic in comparison. Your bleating about downvotes is unbelievable. Why don't you go and vote if you care so much about votes? By the way, wtf is bing?

Comment: @Berwyn Sorry :( but the answer is complete correct and I will not stop defending correct Answers from wrong and misleading Downvotes when they happen.  My familiarity with the internals of the G give me cause to avoid them.  I do like the '+1' idiom though so +1 for that.